# Passing Data to a Navigation controller inside a Tab View controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm pretty new to iOS development.

I have a problem passing data between views in a tab bar controller.

```
ViewController // First tab in the tab bar with a number pad for entering numbers into a label
SongController // Second tab embed within a Navigation Controller searches database for number entered in the first tab and displays lyrics in a web view
```

I'm try to pass the value from the label in the ViewController to a method in my SongController.

In `ViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender {

int songNum = [self.numberLabel.text intValue];

NSString *songNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",songNum];

if ([songNumber  isEqual: @"0"] || [songNumber isEqual: @""]) {

    [self.numberLabel setText:@""];

    UIAlertView *songNotFound = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle: @"Sorry"
                          message: @"This song could not be found."
                          delegate: nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [songNotFound show];
}
else
{        
    NSLog(@"%@", songNumber);

    SongController *sing = [[SongController alloc]init];

    sing.songNumberFromChooser = songNumber;

    self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
}
```

The NSString `songFromNumberChooser` in `SongController` isn't being changed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the NSString value changed using NSUserDefaults.

```
- (IBAction)goButton:(id)sender {
   .....
}
else
{        
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:songNumber forKey:@"number"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
```

And then retrieved it in the viewWillAppear method of the `SongController`

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    songNumber = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"number"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like you are actually passing the data between the tabs. the best way to do that would be to use delegation pattern. I will let you read [this tutorial](http://enroyed.com/ios/how-to-pass-data-between-ios-tab-bars-using-delegate/) first. If there is something that still doesn't work, we can hack it out together.

Comment: I tried that as well but it seems its different when one of the tab bar items is embed in a navigation controller

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this is not working is because you are creating a new instance of SongController, as opposed to assigning the value to the SongController that you already have instantiated in your tab bar controller.

Instead try this to get the one you've already created:

```
SongController* sing = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];

sing.songNumberFromChooser = songNumber;

self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new instance of `SongController`, while what you should be doing is accessing the existing one managed by the UITabBarController, and setting `songNumberFromChooser` on that controller.